# How to get nonfiction of every incoming/outgoing BEP20 Wallet transaction on a webhook URL?

Tags: blockchain, web3js, ethers.js

I have an application where i have 0...2000 BEP20 Wallet address and I want to send a notification to the user when any transaction has occurred on a particular address.

I already have a system to send a notification to the user but I don't know how can I listen to the wallet transactions.